# What is an environment in programming?

Tags: environment

This may seem like a simple question, but I keep getting caught up in it. The word environment seems to be thrown around a lot, but I can't find a definite answer for my question. Environment variables, and and software development environment both have the word environment. Java Runtime Environment also uses this word, but does it mean the same for everything? Is this word even that significant?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It means the same thing it means in the real world - everything around the space in which you live. Development environments surround the code you're writing and often the user interface you're designing. The Java runtime environment surrounds the Java code that is being run and provides all of the necessary support and functionality you use in your  code. Environmental variables are variables that are set that affect things around them - for instance, the PATH variable affects how the operating system locates executable files when you type their name on the command line.

Comment: Thank you, different environments work differently depending on what it is used for?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Environments are different. The environment in the Sahara desert is vastly different than the environment in SIberia. The Java environment is much different than the .Net environment. Clearly, *different environments* are *different*, or they wouldn't be *different*, would they?

Comment: Yep, this makes seance. Thank you